# Should I use {} or {0} to initialise an array/struct?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, braced-init-list

I have a faint memory of reading that code like `int x[4] = {};` used to initialize a struct/array to default values is relying on a non standard (but widespread) extension that first appeared in gcc, and the correct version (as apparently stated in the standard) is `int x[4] = { 0 };`

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C the initializer list is defined the following way

```
initializer:
assignment-expression
{ initializer-list }
{ initializer-list , }
```

While in C++ it is defined the following way

```
braced-init-list:
{ initializer-list ,opt }
{ }
```

As you can see C++ allows an empty brace-init list while in C initializer list may not be omitted.

So you may write in C++

```
int x[4] = {};
```

However in C this definition does not satisfies the Standard (though it can be an implementation-defined language extension). So you have to write

```
int x[4] = { 0 };
```

In the both cases elements of the array will be zero-initialized.

Comment: As an additional note, a literal zero is a valid initialization constant for all types, and represents the value used by default initialization of static objects.  So `static T foo = {0};` will initialize `foo` to the same value as `static T foo`, and within a function `T bar = {0};` will initialize `bar` to the same value as `foo` had been initialized.